# Get directory of both internal storage and sd card if exist

Tags: java, android

I need to get directory of both internal storage and SD card if exists. but I've searched and I didn't find something helpful. how can i do that? i need to scan both of them for specific type of files. this code gives me Internal Storage Directory and not my SD card:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/");
```

Comment: You do not have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+. You have access to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You also have access to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), assuming that you have permission from the user. You are welcome to query the `MediaStore` for files with particular MIME types, and that usually covers removable storage.

Comment: but how does file manager applications work? they have access to both of them @CommonsWare

Comment: Pre-installed file managers can be granted additional rights by the device manufacturer. Third-party file managers are limited to internal storage and external storage. Many, if not most, Android users only have internal and external storage, as many Android devices do not have removable storage, and those that do may not have any sort of card installed.

Comment: so directory of internal storage and external storage is what all i want @CommonsWare

Comment: Then the answer that you have below is the right answer, as it points you to a discussion of external storage. You can read more about external storage at [the blog post that I linked to previously](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: my phone is lg g3 and it has a 16gb sd card and 32gb internal. using that code gives me just internal storage and my question is how to get sd cards directory? @CommonsWare

Comment: "using that code gives me just internal storage" -- from the standpoint of the Android SDK, that is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "my question is how to get sd cards directory?" -- there is no support for that in Android, sorry. This is all covered in the blog posts that I have been linking to in these comments.

Comment: thank you @CommonsWare that was big help but not solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are thousands of links for tutorials, Android developer page is one of the many, below is the link ;

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

As far as I know, you can have access to your app internal dir and query whether sd card is mounted etc. But to get full access to device internal Dir? I doubt it because it would be breach of user's privacy. You even require user permission to query external storage

Comment: I've already checked that link but not helping me to do what i want

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```